# Cakephp HABTM association is not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I need an association where therapists have many children and visa-versa.

I have 3 tables:

therapists
children
children_therapists

You can see the association below:

Therapist.php

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Child' =>
                array(
                               'className' => 'Children',
                               'joinTable' => 'children_therapists',
                               'foreignKey' => 'therapist_id',
                               'associationForeignKey' => 'child_id',
                               'unique' => true,
                               'conditions' => '',
                               'fields' => '',
                               'order' => 'Child.last_name',
                               'limit' => '',
                               'offset' => '',
                               'finderQuery' => '',
                               'with' => ''
                           )
    );
```

In the Child.php model, I tried this code:

```
public $useTable = 'children';
```

but that didn't work.

When I code against it, I get the following error:

Missing Database Table

Error: Table childrens for model Child was not found in datasource default.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: The problem is with the **Children model**, not the Child model. Cake is looking for the table for Children (conventionally would be called `childrens`). You need to set `$useTable = 'children';` inside the Children model.

Comment: Alternatively, if Children isn't actually a model, you need to change `className => Children` to Child in the association.

Answer (score 0):

### The Child model is not used

Because the code in the question does not reference it.

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Child' => array(
       'className' => 'Children',
//                    ^ Supposed to be a model name
```

It references the `Children` model which doesn't exist.

To highlight the meaning of the array key and className keys compare to:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friend' => array(
    //  ^ Whatever you want
           'className' => 'Child',
    //                    ^ A model name
```

### A simple fix

To correct the question asked, simply replace

```
'className' => 'Children'
```

with

```
'className' => 'Child'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. 

When I change the className to 'Child', I get this error:
Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function schema() on a non-object 
File: /var/www/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php 
Line: 3575

Comment: Then there is more wrong than what is in the question =) - look at [the line of code in your app](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.0/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3577) and determine what it is trying to access (i.e. what is `$assoc`) and why it's not a model object.